# How to read error62 in strace log?

Tags: linux, strace

I am trying to read an output of strace log.
I got this line:

```
write(3, "Error. The program should receiv"..., 62Error. The program should receive a single argument. Exiting.
) = 62
```

Can you help me to read this line? What "62Error" means?

Comment: @oguzismail no, doesn't that mean write wrote 62 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What "62Error" means?

This strace output was probably got mixed with program output.

`62` part should be from strace output and `Error` part should be from program output. Normally strace output should be:

```
write(3, "Error. The program should receiv"..., 62) = 62
```

And program output should be:

```
Error. The program should receive a single argument. Exiting.
```

Try to separate strace output from program output with `-o` option:

```
strace -o filename program
```

Comment: I get for "strace -o filename program" this message: "strace: must have PROG [ARGS] or -p PID
 Try 'strace -h' for more information."
Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: "strace -o filename program" - that was just example, you should substitute "program" with your program name or provide a pid number: `-p <PID>`. I don't know how exactly you were invoking strace.